# how to handle long running queries in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I have created a web application with ASP.Net and i hosted it on IIS. In this application there are some forms having log running queries which take more than 30 seconds to run and as i run any query of them all the other forms get slow sometimes it shows like computer is hanged.

Comment: Have you tried profiling these queries to see why they take so long? Why not include some of the long running ones in your question?

Comment: Yes actually these tables included in this queries having complex joins and more data that's why these are taking time

Comment: Show them in your question.